# Mostrar el ventana de diseño

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Soy muy principiante en el uso de visual basic (Ahora estoy Usando VB 2010) y estoy creando un programa, pero el tema es que por error cerré la ventana del diseño y estoy en la ventana del código  , solo me muestra el diseño cuando compilo el programa ,pero si quiero agregar mas botones no puedo,como puedo hacer para visualizar de nuevo la ventana del diseño

Answer (score 0):

Click derecho al raton y pulsa `Ver Diseñador` o con el teclado el hotkey `Mayus + f7`